# Make django-admin-sortable and django-parler work together

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-admin, django-parler

I have two models with many-to-many relation using `through` table

```
# models.py

class Item(TranslatableModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)  # this one is translatable

class Person(TranslatableModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)  # this one is translatable
    items = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Item',
        through='PersonItem',
    )


class PersonItem(Sortable):

    class Meta(Sortable.Meta):
        ordering = ['order']

    person = models.ForeignKey('Person')
    item = SortableForeignKey('Item')
```

But I am not able to have sorted `Item`s in admin

```
# admin.py

class PersonItemInline(TranslatableTabularInline, SortableTabularInline):
    model = PersonItem
    form = PersonItemForm
    extra = 1

class PersonAdmin(TranslatableAdmin):
    form = PersonForm
    inlines = [
        PersonItemInline
    ]


admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

When I inherit from `translatable` first I lose sorting feature. When I'm trying to inherit from `sortable` first I have following error

> NoReverseMatch Reverse for 'person_person_do_sorting' with arguments
>   '(239,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Env (python 3):
`django==1.10.7`, `django-parler==1.6.5`, `django-admin-sortable==2.0.19`

Comment: Issue on github https://github.com/alsoicode/django-admin-sortable/issues/190

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@most-wanted ensure that the inhreritance order is correct:

```
class PersonItemInline(SortableTabularInline, TranslatableTabularInline):
    ...
class PersonAdmin(SortableAdmin, TranslatableAdmin):
    ...
```

and override `change_form_template_extends` in `PersonAdmin` class like this:

```
class PersonAdmin(SortableAdmin, TranslatableAdmin):
    change_form_template_extends = 'admin/parler/change_form.html'
```

Comment: Ensuring that order is correct and adding custom `change_form` template (which combines sortable and translatable) did the work.